# Curve modifier doesn't follow curve in the correct axis

Tags: modifiers, axis

Apologies If I am not using correct words and names for the modifiers. I tried to follow a simple blender plant creation tutorial but in the last section I came across a problem that I cannot solve. I created a bezier curve for the sake of adjusting plant's stalk, but when I added curve modifier, my stalk changed it's position. According to the tutorial, I should simply choose 'deform axis Z" but when I click it, plant's stalk is still in an incorrect place. Please see images below. Any solutions? I tried to look for answers but didn't come across anything quite the same.
Thanks in advance!
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi, I did, I am not quite sure how this platform works, so I copied the link that was created after I added the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/74c301541e8b4ae4bc01c7eb69775776

Answer (score 0):

- Apply the rotation of your curve (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)
- In *Edit* mode, right click and *Switch Direction* so that the normals go from bottom to top
- You’ve keyframed the *Curve* modifier's *Deform Axis*, not sure why, so maybe delete the keyframe, and find the right axis (which seems to be -X)

Your stalk doesn’t completely follow the curve but it’s because it is not originally completely straight,  it’s already a bit curvy before you give it the *Curve* modifier